# Vscode """ """ string when comment color somehow got turned to dark green

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmlcs.png)

One day, the color """ """ string when comment color somehow got turned to dark green.
While the string color remain light orange.
I had try to change comments' color in settings, but it only effect the # comment.

```
"editor.fontLigatures": false,
"workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",

"editor.tokenColorCustomizations":{
    "comments":"#a1b876",
}
```

how do I change the color of """ """ string when comment to custom color or at least normal string color?

Comment: That looks like a docstring comment.  Look to see if vscode has a special setting for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`"""` is not a comment, it's still a string.**

As for why the two triple-quote strings in the picture have different colors, because hhh is recognized as a docstring.

[image]

You can change the color with the following settings

```
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "[Default Dark+]": {
            "textMateRules": [
                {
                    "name": "docstring",
                    "scope": "string.quoted.docstring.multi.python",
                    "settings": {
                        "foreground": "#FF0000"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "string",
                    "scope": "string.quoted.multi.python",
                    "settings": {
                        "foreground": "#0de711"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

[image]